# How to switch to a new tab

Tags: smartgwt

I currently have a TabSet of tabs.

```
List<Tab> tabList = new ArrayList<Tab>();
tabList.add(createTab("tab1", "Tab1", new TabPanel()));
tabList.add(createTab("tab2", "Tab2", new TabPanel()));
TabSet tabSet = new TabSet();
tabSet.setTabs(tabList.toArray(new Tab[tabList.size()]));
```

I want to be able to add a double click handler in a grid, by double clicking something, it will switch to one of the tabs Im not currently on. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your click handler call [`selectTab()`](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/tab/TabSet.html#selectTab(int)) on the `tabSet`. Just pass in either the zero based index of the tab, the string id of the tab, or the particular `Tab` instance.

Comment: thanks. im having a hard time getting the tabSet to call selectTab from the grid i'm currently on.

Comment: It's a ListGrid named mainGrid, which is one of the tabs. there is a button:
button.addDoubleClickHandler(handler here); I want to be able to double click this button, switch to another tab

Comment: Whatever class creates your ListGrid needs to store a reference to the TabSet instance as a member variable. So you may need to pass in that TabSet instance from wherever you create it if it's in a different class. Then in your handler you will have access to the TabSet so you can call `selectTab`.